# What are some Alternatives to enumerate function in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a question I need  to solve using python, using a `def` function. Basically take a list of numbers, and then and add a letter at the end of each element in the list.

I was finally able to do it, but for various reasons I need to find an alternative way that does not use `enumerate`. Is there any way to make this work without using `enumerate` function, something simpler. Here is my working code:

```
def addletter( mylist ):
    for index, item in enumerate(mylist):
        mylist[index] = str(item)
    for i in range(len(mylist)):
        mylist[i] = mylist[i] + randomletter
    return

# Now you can call addletter function
mylist = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,];
randomletter= 'a'
addletter( mylist );
print (mylist)
```

Comment: Enumerate just returns an index and the value. You could just add a counter initialized at 0 and add 1 at the end of each loop. The counter will be the current index

Comment: I would like to know the reasons behind not using enumerate .

Comment: This sounds a lot like a homework question, and your teacher thinks you haven't quite solved it in the way they intended. For instance, is `addletter` meant to mutate (change) its input list, or is it meant to create a new output list?

Comment: `enumerate` is not even needed here, you don't care about the index, just iterate over the list, convert int to string and add 'a' to the string

Comment: @Chris_Rands you need the index to change the value of an element.

Comment: @ruohola returning a new list would be better, anyway you could just reassign to the same list slice `mylist[:] = ['{}a'.format(i) for i in mylist]`

Comment: Dunes, you are absolutely correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done without the enumerate function:
(you can remove the other loop, and you don't have to call `return`, python will automatically `return None`):

```
def add_letter(mylist):
    for i in range(len(mylist)):
        mylist[i] = str(mylist[i]) + randomletter


# Now you can call addletter function
mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, ];
randomletter = 'a'
add_letter(mylist)
print(mylist)
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. I had the 2nd loop, was to trying to figure out how to use range instead of enumerate.

Comment: @ruohola This is obviously homework. You shouldn't provide a complete solution when answering a homework question, only hints.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I'd agree, but since he was so close to the solution, I didn't see the harm.